# Read Text file And increment String Version

Tags: c#, parsing, file-io, replace

I am working on small application in c#. in which I have to read the text file and update the specific number (+1). Can anybody help me

Serial No 'major version number'.'minor version number'.'Service pack number'
(Update the minor version number to +1 only, second digit from Sr Number)

One of the problems if how to handle the locating of the Serial line as sometimes it contains: `SerialNo:` and sometimes `Sr No`

Text file information as below

```
Product Code: Prd1001
Description:  Item 1
SerialNo :  1.0.0
Mfg Date: 12/Jan/2017
```

After Updated

```
Product Code: Prd1001
Description:  Item 1
SerialNo :  1.1.0
Mfg Date: 12/Jan/2017
```

or

```
Product Code: Prd1001
Description:  Item 1
Sr No 1.1.1 
Mfg Date: 12/Jan/2017
```

After updated

```
Product Code: Prd1001
Description:  Item 1
Sr No 1.2.1 
Mfg Date: 12/Jan/2017
```

Can anybody help me

Thanks

Comment: File.ReadAllLines then For Each Line just check if contains Sr No or SerialNo if it does modify the line https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Show what code you have so far that isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Example code on how to update the first file format:

```
var text = "Product Code: Prd1001\r\nDescription:  Item 1\r\nSerialNo :  1.0.0\r\nMfg Date: 12/Jan/2017";
var updatedText = "";

foreach(var line in text.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None))
{
    if(line.StartsWith("SerialNo"))
    {
        var parts = line.Split(new char[] { ':' });
        var serial = parts[1].Trim().Split(new char[] { '.' });

        var majorVersionNo = int.Parse(serial[0]);
        var minorVersionNo = int.Parse(serial[1]);
        var servicePackNo = int.Parse(serial[2]);

        // Make updates. Example:
        servicePackNo++;

        updatedText += "SerialNo : " + majorVersionNo + "." + minorVersionNo + "." + servicePackNo + Environment.NewLine;

    }
    else
    {
        updatedText += line + Environment.NewLine;
    }
}

Debug.Write(updatedText);
```

Comment: please check [answer]

Comment: @Mederic What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Zero explanation of what you used to do it or why you only half answered the question since your just taking care of one possibility he described. If you just post code at least give minimum explanations and have it complete

Comment: Thank you very much for quick reply. I will implement it.

Comment: @Mederic Please note that the code exposes clear variable names and rather basic, self-explanatory functions. In my opinion it does not require further comments as they would only make it less readable. Also note that this is just an example solution which can be easily updated by the OP. It is not clear from the question whether the code must handle multiple file formats or whether simply one format has not been established yet.

Comment: I never said the code isn't readable but you could explain the way it works specially when you use split(":") but one of the examples is: `Sr No 1.1.1` This would lead index out of range ;)

Comment: @chintu If an answer meets your requirements consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it.

Comment: @Mederic I have updated the answer, although the lack of a colon seems like a typo to me.

Comment: There have two kind of pattern as (SerialNo :  1.1.0 and Sr No 1.1.1 or Sr No 2.0)

Answer (score 0):

I would propose this `Sub` which lets you handle which type of **version index** to increment.

- **Version Index = 0** increment Major Version
- **Version Index = 1** increment Minor Version
- **Version Index = 2** increment Service Pack Version

You can easily call this to change Minor Version for example:

```
ChangeVersion("c:\test.txt", 1)
```

I Decided to use a simple approach of reading every line and checking if it contained your Serial Operator then it decomposes your line to isolate the version and increment depending on the chosen setting.

To locate the first occurrence of the version I used the `IndexOfAny` and then a `CharArray` of numbers as it is faster and less memory consuming than using `Regex`. 
And here is the function:

```
'Version Index = 0 increment Major Version
'Version Index = 1 increment Minor Version
'Version Index = 2 increment Service Pack Version
Public Sub ChangeVersion(ByVal FilePath As String, ByVal VersionIndex As Integer)
    Dim lines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(FilePath)
    For i = 0 To lines.Count - 1
        Dim line As String = lines(i)
        If line.Contains("Sr No") Or line.Contains("SerialNo") Then
            Dim ix As Integer = line.IndexOfAny("1234567890".ToCharArray)
            Dim early As String = line.Substring(0, ix)
            Dim sversions() As String = Split(line.Remove(0, ix), ".")
            If VersionIndex = 0 Then
                sversions(0) = CInt(sversions(0)) + 1
            ElseIf VersionIndex = 1 Then
                sversions(1) = CInt(sversions(1)) + 1
            ElseIf VersionIndex = 2 Then
                sversions(2) = CInt(sversions(2)) + 1
            Else
                MsgBox("Version Index Error")
            End If
            Dim NewVersion As New Version(sversions(0), sversions(1), sversions(2))
            lines(i) = early & NewVersion.ToString
        End If
    Next
    IO.File.WriteAllLines(FilePath, lines)
End Sub
```